# Bootstrap gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going to create a new Rails project, and as I know I should use gem 'bootstrap-sass', it's not a problem for me. But I have one question - why I should use gem instead of just adding some files (CSS and JS) directly to index.html? Can you explain me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think you "should use gem 'bootstrap-sass?' You can have custom CSS and JS without Bootstrap. What's more, you can use CSS and JS without directly adding files to your individual views by using the [Rails asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), which is the standard approach in a Rails application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gem or source files don't make any big difference.

But, when you use gem it's easier to update... you need just update the gem and it's done! And when you use the source files, you must download the new version and replace the old files. I think it's the big deal when using gem: easer to update.